# Which permission should I use for a role to see a shortcut to Custom Block Library?

Tags: 8, users

I have a custom block that is a site-wide announcement. I have a role, "Announcement Editor", for those people who I want to edit that message.

Most of our users have restricted permissions, and don't have access to the "Structure" menu, etc. We use shortcuts to allow them to see items they can't navigate to through menus. This was set up by a developer who is no longer here.

I want to add a shortcut, "Blocks", linking to `/admin/structure/block/block-content` to these users' menu. I have added it to the default shortcuts for the site. It shows up for Admin users:

[image]

However it doesn't show up for other users:

[image]

What permission(s) do I need to add for users to see this shortcut?

**Edit** Authenticated users have the permission `use shortcuts` already:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions defined for the module are:

```
administer shortcuts:
  title: 'Administer shortcuts'
customize shortcut links:
  title: 'Edit current shortcut set'
  description: 'Editing the current shortcut set will affect other users if that set has been assigned to or selected by other users. Granting "Select any shortcut set" permission along with this permission will grant permission to edit any shortcut set.'
switch shortcut sets:
  title: 'Select any shortcut set'
  description: 'From all shortcut sets, select one to be own active set. Without this permission, an administrator selects shortcut sets for users.'
access shortcuts:
  title: 'Use shortcuts'
```

1. To see the shortcuts you need the permission **Use shortcuts**.
2. To see the shortcuts in the toolbar you need the permission **Use the administration toolbar**
3. To see the shortcut for the page **/admin/structure/block/block-content** you need the permission **Administer blocks**

Comment: Users already have that permission. See latest edit.

Comment: @user1359 I update my answer too :-)